# Functional component event is still active when state is toggled - REACT MAPBOX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, use-effect, use-state

I'm trying to build an app where you can toggle effects by clicking on the navitems.

On the nav items I have an event listener that toggles state

```
const [marker, setMarker] = useState(false);

onClick={() => setMarker(!marker)}
```

The idea is when it's set to true, you can click on the map to set a waypoint. And when it's false, clicking does the default behavior.

I tried using an if statement like this

```
    if (marker) {
      map.current.on('click', (e) => {
        new mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat(e.lngLat).addTo(map.current);
        // Create a new marker.
      });
    }
```

Whether state is true or false, you can still place a waypoint after toggling it for the first time.

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing here? I know it's something stupid.

Comment: just guessing here but is it possible that mapboxgl has its own click listener that it is going to respond to regardless of your marker variable and you need to set some sort of isReadonly property on the map?

Comment: yeah it looks like the map has an 'interactive' boolean property that you probably want to set to your marker bool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've faced the same problem when I began to use React Hooks!
Don't worry, that's because you have no code for removing the added `click` event for `map` Ref!
So you just need to cleanup the `click` event for the map object!

```
useEffect(() => {
    function clickHandler(e) {
        new mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat(e.lngLat).addTo(map.current);
        // Create a new marker.
    }
    if (marker) {
        map.current.on('click', (e) => {
            clickHandler(e)
        });
    }
    return () => {
        map.current.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler)
    }
}, [marker]);
```

Please try this way.. Good luck..

Comment: Oh my, you are a saint sir. Thank you kindly.